# Python pandas : Single column to multiple columns based on the spacing at lower levels

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert the below data structure to a data frame with multiple columns ?

```
d =[{'header1':'          Energy','Header2':'8.87'}, 
            {'header1':'               Energy','Header2':'8.87'}, 
            {'header1':'                    Energy Equipment & Services','Header2':'6.83'}, 
            {'header1':'                         Oil & Gas Equipment & Services','Header2':'6.83'}, 
            {'header1':'                              ENERFLEX LTD','Header2':'1.9'}, 
            {'header1':'                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels','Header2':'8.9'}, 
            {'header1':'                         Integrated Oil & Gas','Header2':'6.86'}, 
            {'header1':'                              CENOVUS ENERGY INC','Header2':'12.97'}, 
            {'header1':'                              SUNCOR ENERGY INC','Header2':'55'}]
        df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Expected output

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Colum4|Column5|Amount
      Energy|||||8.87
      Energy|               Energy||||8.87
      Energy|               Energy|                    Energy Equipment & Services|||6.83
      Energy|               Energy|                    Energy Equipment & Services|                         Oil & Gas Equipment & Services||6.83
      Energy|               Energy|                    Energy Equipment & Services|                         Oil & Gas Equipment & Services|                              ENERFLEX LTD|1.9
      Energy|               Energy|                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels|||8.9
      Energy|               Energy|                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels|                         Integrated Oil & Gas||6.86
      Energy|               Energy|                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels|                         Integrated Oil & Gas|                              CENOVUS ENERGY INC|12.97
      Energy|               Energy|                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels|                         Integrated Oil & Gas|                              SUNCOR ENERGY INC|55
```

Comment: the output does have multiple columns? header1 and header2, just like the data you provided....maybe you could explain how you expect to turn your input into your desired output or what the formatting of your desired output means? seems kind of random

Comment: You are trying to save an outline in a dataframe, which is not common and there are not many functions in pandas to handle outlines. Why do you need a dataframe? What will you do with the df once you have it?

Comment: Take a look at [series.st.slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html). You can loop a hardcoded list of integer indices and create new columns by slice, then use `df.ffill(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the values in header1 on tabs (or 5 spaces in your case) to expand it to a dataframe in pretty much the right format: `str.split(" {5}", expand=True)`. Then you can forward fill the empty values. After that it's just cleanup and renaming columns.

```
new_df = (
    df["header1"]
    .str.split(" {5}", expand=True)
    .replace("", method="ffill")
    .replace("", np.nan)
    .dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    .fillna("")
)
new_df.columns = [f"Column{i + 1}" for i in range(new_df.shape[1])]
new_df["Amount"] = df["Header2"]
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this exactly what  I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d =[{'header1':'          Energy','Header2':'8.87'}, 
            {'header1':'               Energy','Header2':'8.87'}, 
            {'header1':'                    Energy Equipment & Services','Header2':'6.83'}, 
            {'header1':'                         Oil & Gas Equipment & Services','Header2':'6.83'}, 
            {'header1':'                              ENERFLEX LTD','Header2':'1.9'}, 
            {'header1':'                    Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels','Header2':'8.9'}, 
            {'header1':'                         Integrated Oil & Gas','Header2':'6.86'}, 
            {'header1':'                              CENOVUS ENERGY INC','Header2':'12.97'}, 
            {'header1':'                              SUNCOR ENERGY INC','Header2':'55'}]
```

Extracted the header 1 keys to a csv file

```
with open ('listofD.csv', 'w') as f:
    content=""
    for dict in d:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            if key=='header1':
                text = value+'\n'
                content=content+text
                f.writelines(text)
```

Parsed hierarchy based on indents

```
indentation = []
indentation.append(0)
depth = 0

f = open("listofD.csv", 'r')
contentz=[]
line_count=0
for line in f:
    print(line)
    line_count += 1

    line = line[:-1]

    contenty = line.strip()
    indent = len(line) - len(contenty)
    if indent > indentation[-1]  or line_count==1:
        depth += 1
        indentation.append(indent)

    elif indent < indentation[-1]:
        while indent < indentation[-1]:
            depth -= 1
            indentation.pop()

        if indent != indentation[-1]:
            raise RuntimeError("Bad formatting")

    contentz.append(("\t"*depth)+contenty)
```

Put that in a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame([sub.split("\t") for sub in contentz])
```

Filled all the '' as NaNs and None as ''

```
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: x is None)
cols = df.columns[(mask).any()]
for col in df[cols]:
    df.loc[mask[col], col] = ' '
df
```

Removed all blank columns and Filled the blanks with previous row value

```
df=df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df=df.ffill(axis = 0)
```

Merged the header to the data frame

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
df.merge(df1['Header2'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. This helps me. but I accepted the above answer as its very efficient and short